# What do you call a function that takes a value and returns a function that returns that value?

Tags: javascript

I am trying out a more functional style with Javascript using Lodash and compose. I notice that I sometimes need a function that returns a value. So was wondering what this was called so I can find out if Lodash actually has this method.

```
var returnFn = function (i) {
  return function () {
    return i;
  };
};
```

Example:

```
_.compose(doSomething, returnFn({ foo: 'bar' });
```

Instead of:

```
_.compose(doSomething, function () {
    return { foo: 'bar' };
});
```

Comment: are you talking about what is the nomenclature or the pattern name of doing in this way? or you want to call the function to execute?

Comment: In Common Lisp, it's called [CONSTANTLY](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cons_1.htm).  I don't know that I've come across it in the wild, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What do you call a function that takes a value and returns a function that returns that value?

What you have seems to be a [curryied](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) [identity function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function), which in Haskell is known as [`const`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aconst). As it returns a function, it is a [higher order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), maybe also called function [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28software_concept%29). The returned function - a [constant function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_function) - is a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) as it has access to the outer function's argument.

> so I can find out if Lodash actually has this method.

No, it doesn't. However, you can easily compose it yourself by [`_.bind`ing](http://lodash.com/docs#bind) [`_.partial`](http://lodash.com/docs#partial) to the [`_.identity`](http://lodash.com/docs#identity) function:

```
var returnFn = _.bind(_.partial, null, _.identity);
```

Your plain implementation will be lots of faster though…

> ```
> _.compose(doSomething, returnFn({ foo: 'bar' }));
> ```

What you're doing there *is* just [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application), and you should not use `compose` for it. Go with

```
_.partial(doSomething, {foo: 'bar'});
```

Answer (score 2):

They are called [higher order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).

Answer (score 2):

A function that generates another function is called **[higher order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)**, as Ingo said.

A function that returns its first argument is called **[identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function)**.